# Copy permissions from owner

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, file-permissions, chmod, recursive

How can I copy the all file permissions of a folder from owner to users?

Imagine that I have:

```
-rw-r-----  1 124982 5000   201 2012-06-24 06:45 documentation.html
```

I want to change to:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 124982 5000   201 2012-06-24 06:45 documentation.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be either

```
chmod 0644 documentation.html
```

or you can do

```
chmod a+r documentation.html
```

To change modes recursively on a folder (i.e for each file in a folder), do:

```
chmod -R <mode> <path>
```

But be careful - this changes directory modes as well, which differ from file mode in their use of the "execute" permission.

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the values of rwx from ownser and set to all?

Comment: From what? What is owner in this context?